# Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2: "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

After restarting my Windows machine, I received this error trying to open my Ubuntu 18.04 WSL2 instance.

```
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.                                                                                                       
Press any key to continue...
```

It had been working totally normally before the restart.

Answer (score 153):

Restarting the vmcompute service worked for me. From an elevated PowerShell (close WSL2 first though!):

```
Get-Service vmcompute | Restart-Service
```

And then run WSL2 again.

Comment: This worked for me .. but I had to do it via Task Manager. Doing it via a powershell console wouldnt work cos I dont have admin privs. I tried the other suggestions like restarting lxssManager but that didnt help. Restarting vmcompute did.

Comment: Did not work for me, I get `Restart-Service : Service 'Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cann
ot open vmcompute service on computer '.'.`

Comment: @ihatetoregister what do you get if you do a Get-Service vmcompute? You may need to stop the process to then start the service Get-Process | where-object{$_.processname -eq "vmcompute"}

Comment: @ihatetoregister had similar issue, realized had not closed WSL2. Did that and error resolved.

Comment: @ihatetoregister I got the same error, so I went to task manager and stopped it manually :). Then launching WSL worked.

Comment: `Get-Service vmcompute | Restart-Service` worked if I run PowerShell as admin

Comment: @ihatetoregister I had had the same error when I ran the command without admin rights... Running as administrator worked for me.

Comment: Can I add it somewhere in the boot script? Its stopping whenever I am rebooting my system

Comment: @Kundan you could possibly add it to your PowerShell profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2) so that it executes when you open PowerShell. It does mean you will need to change your execution profile though, which is rarely a good thing to do.

Comment: This worked for me. I started facing this issue post switching to windows 11. I am not sure this is related to that.

Answer (score 9):

If  you are on active directory, it might be because of your group policy settings. Open command prompt w/ Administrator rights and run following command:

```
gpupdate /force
```

And run WSL/Ubuntu again. It worked for me.

Comment: Does this have to be done on a per-session basis or is it a one off?

Comment: No longer seems to work on windows 11 :(

Answer (score 8):

Google returned a lot of complicated solutions for when you're dealing with this on a real server, but for personal WSL2 use, my coworker and I both found that Windows had simply disabled Hyper-V when it restarted.

To turn it back on:

1. Search for and open "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. Check the box next to Hyper-V
3. Restart your system

Comment: Does the error appear again on restart with that solution?

Comment: Here's the PowerShell command for that. Run as admin:
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you have a Group Policy in your AD-domain that modifies the "Logon as service" privileges.

Ask your IT admin to add "**NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines**" (Well known SID S-1-5-83-0) to the Group Policy that modifies this privilege (in my case it was the *default domain policy* that modified "Logon As Service").

Worth noting is that the IT Admin has to add this special group from a computer/server that has Hyper-V enabled (or WSL2 components installed). Otherwise the special group will not be available for the admin to add to the policy.

More info [in the GITHUB WSL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5401#issuecomment-1378514769)  or [my blog post](https://kodsnutten.se/wsl2-logon-type-problem-solved/).

Answer (score 2):

It has to be with the Group Policy in your AD-domain that modifies the "Logon as service" privileges that has been addressed avobe. But I only managed to solve it manually.

> Service > Hyper-V host server service > right click > restart

[image]

The picture is in German but it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by updating/reloading my policy settings. To do this execute `gpupdate /force` in your Windows Terminal.

You also have to connect to your organizations network if your user is connected to an AD otherwise the command above will fail. I guess that caused the problem for me since I am not always in that network.

After successful execution you should be granted the right logon type.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My WSL was enabled and Hyper-V was too on Windows 11.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>gpupdate /force
Updating policy...

Computer Policy update has completed successfully.
User Policy update has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

How about when you don't have Hyper-V installed and still gets Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.?

As I don't have Hyper-V installed, I can't restart vmms.

Restart-Service: Cannot find any service with service name 'vmms'.
UPDATE
Just found that in my case I have to run

> Restart-Service vmcompute

, then it works again.