# How to solve "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer." on wsl2 forever

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I know that there is a temporary solution to that error described in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736070/10290286).

But I am interested in a more deeply solution tackle the problem at its roots. Why? Because everyday in the morning after starting my Pc I want to open my wsl2 to start docker... And there it is `Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.` This is so annoying to resolve this problem everyday.

The steps I have to take to sort it (everyday!):

1. Get admin rights from IT
2. Run Windows Terminal as administrator
3. Execute cmd `Get-Service vmcompute | Restart-Service`

This is such a bad user experience and also time consuming and should definitely not be done everyday. I am so tired of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you have a Group Policy in your AD-domain that modifies the "Logon as service" privileges.

Ask your IT admin to add "**NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines**" (Well known SID S-1-5-83-0) to the Group Policy that modifies this privilege (in my case it was the *default domain policy* that modified "Logon As Service").

Worth noting is that the IT Admin has to add this special group from a computer/server that has Hyper-V enabled (or WSL2 components installed). Otherwise the special group will not be available for the admin to add to the policy.

More info [in the GITHUB WSL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5401#issuecomment-1378514769)  or [my blog post](https://kodsnutten.se/wsl2-logon-type-problem-solved/).

Comment: Good luck with all that if you work at a large company